# Did the Feynman heuristic of "simple effects have simple causes" fail for spin statistics?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics, quantum-spin

Someone here recently noted that *"The spin-statistics thing isn't a problem, it is a theorem (a demonstrably valid proposition), and it shouldn't be addressed, it should be understood and celebrated.*"

"Spin statistics" is of course the shorthand way of referencing a most curious fact about the universe, which is this: If a particle of any type has a "spin" measured in whole units of quantized angular momentum, it will be a boson, a group that includes energy-like force particles such as photons. However, if its spin is (rather strangely) off-set by half a unit, it will instead be a fermion, which includes the particles that occupy space and that make up most ordinary matter.

The rule is very simple. The explanation of it is arguably a bit more complicated.

I find it fascinating that Nobel Laureate Richard Feynman worried over this simple theorem for decades, yet he never seemed to find an explanation for it that truly satisfied him. It was *not* a lack of mathematical explanations, I should note. It was because Feynman deeply believed in a rather simple search heuristic: very simple relationships should in general also have simple, easily-conveyed explanations.

Alas, Feynman's last attempt to explain spin statistics, in his *Dirac Lecture*, always seemed to me one of his least clear bits of exposition ever. I am fairly confident Feynman would have assessed his Lecture that way himself, as he tended to be quite brutal in self-critiques on anything related to clarity of explanation.

(I think there is an interesting family insight in that observation, incidentally: Richard Feynman's scientifically inclined father always hoped that his son, who had received the education he was never able to have, would someday explain all those little physics mysteries to him. The young Richard took that duty very seriously, and never really abandoned it, even towards the end of his own life.)

So, my question and challenge: How is everyone doing on Feynman's spin-statistics challenge these days?

Do you, fair reader, have in your hands some truly simple explanation for why whole-spin particles always seems to be bosons, and ones with half-spin offsets always seem to be fermions?

I am not asking for twisty belts and wine glasses (please, *no!*), nor am I asking for something math free... though I do think anyone trying to answer this question should first look at how Feynman handled even complex numbers in his book *QED*. What I *am* asking for is insight, the kind of explanation that makes the reader stop and think *wow, of course that's it, why didn't I see it what way before?*

So, anyone? I probably will not put an explicit bonus on this one, but if someone can provide an explanation that knocks everyone's +1 socks off, I guarantee I'll contribute at least a couple of hundred points to that overall consensus.

Comment: For those who wanted to have a link to Feynman's Dirac lecture. http://youtu.be/cKzzG5DS6V8

Comment: A playlist with all parts of Feynman's Dirac lecture is here: http://youtu.be/cKzzG5DS6V8?list=PLC3D8F5EA631EBA02

Comment: @gns-ank, thanks, I didn't know it was available online!

Comment: Honestly, your question is not clear for me, "why whole-spin particles always seems to be bosons", do you mean why Bosons behaves like Bosons? or why there is two types of fundamental particles? or how spin affects there behavior?

Comment: Hi @TMS: That would be "why are the two always correlated?" Bosons, with wavefunctions that are symmetric under exchange, always seem to have whole-unit spin; while fermions, with wavefunctions that are anti-symmetric under exchange, always seem to have spins that are offset by one half of a spin unit. It's that correlation that's a bit tough to explain in a simple way. I think it would also be fair to say that since there is no simple explanation even for what spin *is* at the level of an electron, which is after all a point-like particle, it's even tougher to explain its impact.

Comment: @Terry Bollinger The existence of particles with spin 1/2, 1, 3/2, 2 etc is a reflection of the Lorentz/Poincare invariance. They are the irreducible representations of the Lortentz/Poincare groups. So your question propably reduces to: why are the fundamental laws (Lagrangians) of nature Lorentz/Poincare invariant? As for why Bosons and why Fermions, these are just associations with names, one type of particles to be called fermions, with spin odd multiple of 1/2, and Bosons, with spin whole integer.

Comment: @JKL, great points. The math is well understood and leads neatly to the two types of statistics. So, if from that math you can show clearly why 1/2 spin offsets always give fermions and whole spins always give bosons, you may have the start of the kind of answer for which Feynman always hoped.

Comment: @TerryBollinger I really thought I had understood your question when I wrote my comment. Now I am really confused. A boson doesn't always give bosons, the electron-positron pair creation from a photon (near an atom)  is a good example. There must be something in your question that doesn't come out clearly enough and, from other comments I have read, I am not the only one who doesn't follow your line of thought. Conservation of angular momentum and symmetry structure dictate the wave functions, and the products of a decay from angular momentum point of view.

Comment: @JKL, oops, by "gives" I did not mean pair creation, which can produce anything with enough energy. From [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin-statistics_theorem) there is this line: "In other words, the spin-statistics theorem states that integer spin particles are bosons, while half-integer spin particles are fermions." The values are more than just labels of course, since spin 1 is the smallest possible unit of quantized angular momentum. That's why folks were more than a tad surprised when (via Stern-Gerlach I think) they found some particles to have half-unit spins.

Comment: It's an interesting point but I'm not sure that simple rules always have simple explanations. For example many statements in number theory are very simple to state yet often very hard to prove. What should we say of Fermat's theorem proved by Wiles?

Comment: On a different note, are you aware of the beautiful proof of the theorem without relativity and field theory?

Comment: @lcv Any "beautiful proof" that doesn't use relativity is wrong, because the theorem requires relativity as a hypothesis. It's _not_ true for nonrelativistic theories.

Comment: @lcv I've seen several such "beautiful" proofs, and they all prove something that is substantially weaker (and less interesting) than the real spin-statistics theorem, then get confused over what they actually showed.

Comment: "The young Richard took that duty very seriously, and never really abandoned it, even towards the end of his own life." Feynman was quoted at both my own father's second wedding (after his first spouse died; Feynman was an obscure grad student when my dad married the first time), and at my own father's funeral. He did indeed take that duty seriously and did it well (and died too young).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest proof of the spin-statistics theorem I know of is shown in the two videos on http://www.motionmountain.net/videos.html
One video shows spin 1/2 behavior, the other video shows that fermion behavior follows automatically.

Comment: +1 for a really nice pair of belt videos, despite my very sincere "please no!" plea on that point :). "Exchanging buckles twice = 720$^{\circ}$" is going to confuse folks who see only a 360$^{\circ}$ rotation, but Feynman and others do explain why that is. Spin 1 becomes "no belts, just buckles", which alas is not mentioned in the description. The shared underlying math is correctly noted. But alas: I'm guessing that most folks who see even a good video like that will go away wondering why belts are "just like spin 1/2"  (spinors) and buckles "just like spin 1". So: Good Feynman capture.

Comment: The belt trick video is a classic, but it's just wrong. It tells us that phases acquired by rotation (related to spin) are related to phases acquired by physically exchanging particles. This is *not* the same thing as the phase associated with particle statistics, which is what the spin-statistics theorem is about, so the video doesn't prove it.

Comment: To say it another way: the spin-statistics theorem only holds for relativistic theories. The belt trick proof doesn't mention relativity anywhere; it proves too much, so it must be wrong.

Comment: @knzhou do not be too quick too dismiss the relevance of the belt trick: in the usual belt trick we take for granted the fact that the location of the belt is unphysical (i.e. we don't 'count' steps where we only move the belt and not the buckles). If these belts are certain strings sticking out of fermions, then relativity could be used to argue that these strings are topological (having to do with the arbitrariness of spatial slices) and can be moved around at will.

Comment: @RubenVerresen Very interesting! Sounds deep, I'll have to think about it some more...